# moving directadmin to directadmin with same provider / nameserver

Tags: linux, centos, hosting, vps, directadmin

we just moved a directadmin VPS (reseller users) to a new directadmin VPS.

1. Backup all users
2. New server restore all users
3. Verify settings

Now my only problem is (and havent found google item on it) that many users move to another hosting provider and hence change the nameservers to point to the new directadmin VPS.

But in our case both old and new directadmin VPS are with the same provider.

**Question**: now what is the correct way of changing the DNS/nameserver settings so that my domain migrates neatly from the old VPS to the new VPS? [put plainly: what do I need to disable or change on the old VPS so that the nameserver knows it should find the new VPS]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is: ask your provider / sysadmin to change the DNS primary master IP to listen the new server.

Apparently a DNS listens to a certain IP for DNS changes. In the specific case that you move your server (1 vps to other vps with different IP) the DNS server is listening for DNS changes on the old IP. It neglects the new DNS settings from the server on the new IP.

When the sysadmin has changed the master IP in DNS to listen to the new server, then the new DNS settings and new domain will be found.

I hope this helps you out - this took me quite while to figure out